# How to properly match TAB in Regex using Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following `test.txt` file

```
# Example:
# Comments
# Comments

MC

Attribute 1
Attribute 2
Attribute 3


---

MC

Attribute 1
Attribute 2
Attribute 3

---

MC 

Attribute 1
Attribute 2
Attribute 3
```

I want to perform

1. Remove comments
2. Remove empty lines
3. Replace `\n` by `\t`
4. Remove turn `\t---\t` into a `\n`

So that I achieve the following

```
MC <TAB> Attribute 1 <TAB> Attribute 2 <TAB> Attribute 3
MC <TAB> Attribute 1 <TAB> Attribute 2 <TAB> Attribute 3
MC <TAB> Attribute 1 <TAB> Attribute 2 <TAB> Attribute 3
```

For some reason the following doesn't work

```
perl -pe "s/#.*//g; s/^\n//g; s/\n/\t/g; s/\t---\t/\n/g" test.txt
```

Producing the output

```
MC  Description --- MC  Description --- MC  Description
```

If I just run the following instead

```
perl -pe "s/#.*//g; s/^\n//g; s/\n/\t/g;" test.txt
```

I also have

```
MC  Description --- MC  Description --- MC  Description
```

It appear that the last command in `s/#.*//g; s/^\n//g; s/\n/\t/g; s/\t---\t/\n/g` is not working.

Comment: Well, you removed _all_ newlines (some replaced by tabs), so it's all on one line;. Those `-` were never touched because there is no pattern `\t---\t` on any one line (that command-line program reads one line at a time).  But it's not quite that simple -- you need to join lines with `MC` and `Description` -- but not others I presume?  Questions: (1) Is it specifically those phrases on lines to join? Or can there be other text? (2) Where are the tabs you need in output --- is it between words `MC` and `Description`?

Comment: Also, you say to remove `\t---\t` -- but there are no such things in input; do you mean to remove all lines with only `---`, and are there yet other lines to keep?

Comment: It is possible that I have content in other lines. All the content that comes after, and before this tag `---` should be considered as a new column, but in the same line, thus separated by `\t`

Comment: In this first part `s/^\n//g;` I believe to be only removing empty lines. New lines should still be present in other lines.

Comment: `that command-line program reads one line at a time` I totally forgot about it.

Comment: So `---` separate what are supposed to become columns?  So if there were `a\n --- b --- c` it should become `a [tab] b [tab] c`? Then when do columns end and a new line should start? (This seems to disagree with "_Remove turn `\t---\t` into a `\n`_" from the question?)  Perhaps you can edit to show a more complete sample of the file you have and what you expect (indicate tabs somehow since they may not show)?

Comment: I don't mean to give you trouble with all this, it's just that I don't understand what you have nor what you need to have

Comment: No, my bad. I meat that, what ever comes before `---` is transformed to become column, what comes after `---` will be put in the next line.

Comment: "_`s/^\n//g;` I believe to be only removing empty lines_"  -- why do you think that? It removes a newline at the beginning of the string.  It doesn't say what else may follow. (But given that it is one-liner it may indeed end up removing only empty lines)

Comment: Example: `a \n a1 \n a2 \n a3 \n --- b \n b1 \n b2 \n b3 \n`. This will become
`a \t a1 \t a2 \n b \t b1 \t b2`

Comment: "_what ever comes before --- is transformed to become column_"  --- so you mean that all lines of input are assembled (changed) into columns ... until `---` comes, after which a new line starts?

Comment: @zdim. Exactly! I just changed the example on the question description for more clarity.

Comment: Oh -- just now the page updated so i see that there was an answer an hour ago ?!?  Then this whole exchange was unnecessary since you got an answer (but at least you got to improve the question :)

Comment: @zdim, Thank you for the insights. Specially by the `one line at a time`. Otherwise I would not have a clue why the original attempt didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say you're removing `\t---\t`, but that doesn't appear to be in the input.

If you want to match a line that has only whitespace and `---` on it, use `^\s*---\s*$`.

```
perl -pe "s/#.*//g; s/^\n//g; s/\n/\t/g; s/^\s*---\s*$/\n/g" test.txt
```

Note that this will leave you with no newline at the end of the file if there is no final `---`.

---

If you want to process the whole line, use `-0`. `-0` controls the "input record separator" which Perl uses to decide what is a line. `-0` alone sets it to null (assuming there are no null bytes) will read the whole file.

Then your original *almost* works. You need to add a `/m` so that `^` matches the beginning of a line as well as the beginning of a string.

```
perl -0pe "s/#.*//g; s/^\n//mg; s/\n/\t/g; s/\t---\t/\n/g" test.txt
```

---

But we can make this simpler! The input record separator separates *records*. Your record separator is `---\n`, so we can set it to that and process each *record* individually.

To set the input record separator to a string, we use [`$/`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles). And to do this in a one-liner, we put it in a `BEGIN` block so it is run only once when the program starts, not for every line.

Finally, we use `-l` to both automatically strip the record separator, which is `---\n`, and to add a newline to the end of each line. That is, it adds a `chomp` at the start and a `$_ .= "\n"` at the end.

```
# Set the input record separator to ---\n.
# -l turns on autochomp to strip the separator.
# -l also adds a newline to each line.
# Strip comments.
# Strip blank lines (again, using /m so ^ works)
# Turn tabs into newlines.
perl -lpe 'BEGIN { $/ = "---\n" } s/#.*//mg; s/^\s*\n//mg; s/\n/\t/g;' test.txt
```

As a bonus, we get newlines on every line, including the last.

---

Finally, we can instead handle this using arrays. Same basic idea as before, but we split them back into lines and use `grep` to filter out unwanted lines. Then we're left with a simple join.

I'll write this one out long-hand so it's easier to read.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -lp

BEGIN { $/ = "---\n" }

# Split into lines.
# Strip comment lines.
# Strip blank lines.
# Join back together with tabs.
$_ = join "\t",
  grep /\S/,
  grep !/^#.*/,
  split /\n/, $_;
```

I find this approach more maintainable; it's easier to deal with an array of lines than everything mashed together in a multi-line string.

Comment: I thought I added the `\t` in `\t---\t` by using  `s/\n/\t/g;`

Comment: @EduardoReis A newline is a new line. The line is "---\n" so you get "---\t".

Comment: @EduardoReis If you want to process the whole file at once, use `-0`.

Comment: Schwern, as far as I understood, my mistake was to account that `-p` process each line individually, as pointed by @zdim right? Since is line by line, I wouldn't get that pattern (`\t---\t`) I was hopping for. Is my understanding right?

Comment: `-0[octal]         specify record separator (\0, if no argument)`. If I understood it properly, you said this would make perl process the file as a whole, instead of line by line, thus my original string command would work, is this it?

Comment: @EduardoReis Yes, it will process the whole file in one go. No, your original doesn't quite work. You need to change `s/^\n//g;` to `s/^\n//mg;`, the `/m` makes `^` also match the beginning of a line, not just the string. What I'd recommend is setting the input separator to `"---\n"`. I'll add it to the answer.